beforeSignIn is not triggering when the user is disabled
I have a simple cloud function that is supposed to handle the users that are banned from our site:
exports.beforeSignIn = functions.auth.user().beforeSignIn((user, context) => {
    const {isBanned} = user.customClaims || {};

    if (isBanned) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('permission-denied', 'This account has been permanently banned due to violating Terms and Conditions');
    }
});

I trigger the customClaim using this cloud function:
exports.setBanStatus = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    const {uid, isBanned} = req.body;

    try {
        await admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, {isBanned});
        return res.json({message: `Ban status updated for user ${uid}`});
    } catch (error) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', error.message);
    }
});

Now, this is working when the user isn't manually disabled from the authentication inside firebase console, and it's showing this error:
Firebase: HTTP Cloud Function returned an error: {"error":{"message":"This account has been permanently banned due to violating Terms and Conditions","status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"}} (auth/internal-error).
However, using this ajax form that I have in signin:
$('#signinbtn').on('click', async () => {
    const email = $('#email').val();
    const password = $('#password').val();

    try {
        await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.code === 'auth/user-disabled') {
            showMessage('User account has been disabled. Please contact us to re-enable your account.');
        } else if (error.code === 'auth/wrong-password') {
            showMessage('Wrong password.');
        } else {
            showMessage(error.message);
        }
    }
});

It's triggering auth/user-disabled and showing User account has been disabled. Please contact us to re-enable your account. to the user when we disable the user, hence beforeSignIn is being taken over.
Is there any workaround for this? And if not, what other way do you suggest we deal with this situation? We need 2 types of user disables, one is when the user disables their account from their profile, and the other is when we disable the user account as means of banning them.
Also, we would like to let the user in if they decide to re-enable their account, i.e a basic sign-in would re-enable their account, instead of sending us an e-mail and asking us to re-enable it.

This sounds like it's working as designed: disabling the user in the Firebase console sets the disabled claim on their profile to true, which blocks them from signing in. Your custom implementation (using a isBanned claim) does nothing to change that, and there is no way to change the behavior of Firebase's handling of the disabled claim.
If you want to always use your own logic for disabling users, you should make sure you have just one claim. I'd recommend creating a custom user management page for your administrators, and in there setting the isBanned property too - or another property that your Cloud Function can then check.

So you're saying I should either use the disabled functionality of firebase, or create my own isBanned and isDisabled claims and check user status based on that? But wouldn't the user be able to login anyway if disabled functionality of firebase isn't turned on for that user?

You can't change the behavior of Firebase's built-in disabled claim. But your setBanStatus blocking function can implement whatever your use-case needs, and can't be bypassed by the user either.

I see, how do I add a middleware that checks if isBanned is set to true and logs the user out and prevents actions? Similar behavior to the disabled of firebase.

I'm confused. Isn't that precisely what your beforeSignIn function does: preventing the user from logging in?

Yes correct, but what about users who are already logged in? disabled functionality of firebase stops the user from doing anything.

It doesn't sign them actively out, but it does indeed prevent their ID token from refreshing (which happens every hours). I don't think there's a blocking Cloud Function for that.

Thanks Frank, this gave me the right path to finding a solution.
